# PHP MYSQL display data in COMBOBOX

Tags: php, html, mysql, combobox

I have this table in my database

```css
create table example
(
   first_name CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   last_name CHAR(20) NOT NULL
   UNIQUE (last_name, first_name)
);
```

then I make a form on php

```html
<html><title>output from database</title>
<body><form action="" method="post">
Name :<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
```

//here will be the combobox

when I press submit, I wish that the name input will be check via database if it existed, and if it existed, the name will be output in big combobox inside the same page of above code.

I've already made the check into database and etc., I just need to put into combobox. I read lots tutorial, I tried, but still I failed. I need guidance please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <?php
      // create a connection
      // read all names as mysql query result to the variable $result
     if(isset($_POST['name'])&&($_POST['name']!=''))
          $name= trim($_POST['name']);
     echo "<select name='name'>";
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
     {
        if($name==$row[name])
           echo "<option value = '".$row[name]."' selected>".$row[name]."</option>";
        else
           echo "<option value = '".$row[name]."'>".$row[name]."</option>"; 
     }
     echo "</select>";
    ?> 
       <html><title>output from database</title>
        <body><form action="" method="post">
        Name :<input type="text" name="name"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
       </form></html>
```

Comment: Don't feel sorry here. Out of programmers' feeling. Start debug, just google your troubles. So you learn-how to not ask questions!